# What was all of the junk in the SES satellite deployment?

Tags: launch, spacex, falcon-9, debris

In the [SES launch on March 4, 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIkPP2LM8DU&t=3083s), when the satellite deployed, there was quite a bit of junk that was released when the satellite was released. What was that?

[image]

Comment: The link in the question contains `v=sIkPP2LM8DU&t=3083s`. 3083 seconds is 51m 23s  but both [that technical webcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIkPP2LM8DU) and the [other, full webcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muDPSyO7-A0) are less than 44 minutes in length. I think it should be 43m 34s = `t=2614` to match T+ 00:32:08. Is SpaceX changing the length of the video? Same for the [comment by @ventsyv](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14333/what-was-all-of-the-junk-in-the-ses-satellite-deployment/15538?noredirect=1#comment37540_14334) below

Answer (score 1):

Probably ice. As the spacecraft goes through the atmosphere water condenses, then freezes. When the satellite is released, some of that ice breaks off.

Comment: It could be, but this was a part of the rocket that was covered in the atmosphere

Comment: Actually after watching the video more closely, it appears like some insulation was ripped. You can see it clearly in the video at 46:45 (T+00:27)

Comment: @ventsyv like I [mentioned above](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14333/what-was-all-of-the-junk-in-the-ses-satellite-deployment/15538?noredirect=1#comment41004_14333) Both the technical and "full" webcast videos on the SpaceX website are less than 44 minutes long. Both of your timestamps are beyond the full length of the videos. I wonder - are they editing the videos and reducing their length?