# What is the icy formation on these rockets?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, fuel, attitude

I've sometimes seen icy formations form and break off of spacecraft.  In [today's SpaceX launch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLNmtUEvI5A), there are a couple examples (times based on video) at [51:55](https://youtu.be/gLNmtUEvI5A?t=51m55s) where you can see it growing:

[image]

Two similar structures are visible at [49:53](https://youtu.be/gLNmtUEvI5A?t=49m53s) (you can see the larger one break off and more gas or something escape a few seconds later), helping clarify:
[image]

or at [50:26](https://youtu.be/gLNmtUEvI5A?t=50m26s), which seems to be on the other side:
[image]

My best guess is that this is frozen propellant for whatever small thrusters keep the rocket on course, though the first time I saw the first example it seemed like something leaking out of the large ring.  If that's it, does this icing cap/clog the thruster and make it less effective, or risk cutting off the course correction capability altogether?